# The authorization page for Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, authorization

I need the authorization page for Marketing Cloud.

For Salesforce, I am able to use the link below:

https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize

Yet, I need the Marketing Cloud version of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URI is: `https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken`

Straight from the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/get-access-token.htm) the whole POST must be as follows :)

```
POST https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "clientId": "YOUR_CLIENT_ID",
    "clientSecret": "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
}

200 OK
{
    "accessToken": "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
    "expiresIn": 3600
}
```

Comment: Hi Javier, thanks a lot for your help. How can I redirect the user to login via Marketing Cloud with that url?  I mean, I need my users to login via Marketing Cloud and redirect them to the previous page.

Comment: @SelimSevim I'm not sure of what you mean with this new question. Regardless, I'd open a up a new question in the system so someone can address it properly :)